# MATLAB: Plot random signal

Tags: matlab, random, plot, signals

My task is to plot a completely random signal.

This is my progress so far:

```
sig_length = 200; % this task is part of a three plot figure so ignore the subplot part
subplot(2,2,1)
hold on
sig = rand(1,sig_length);
plot(1:sig_length,sig)
axis tight
title('Signal')
```

My problem is that I want the interval of the y axis to be -5 to 5. How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want the random signal to go between -5 and 5, or do you want the actual axis to show -5 to 5?

Comment: Well I managed to set the axis to show -5 to 5 by writing 
axis([0 200 -5 5]) 
but the signal still goes from 0 to 1. 
So yeah, I want the signal to reach the values shown on the axis :/

Comment: What do you mean completely random? What distribution do you want to achieve? Uniform? Normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order to set the axis, use  `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])` more documentation can be found http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html
2. In order to create a signal that is centered about 0, with a uniform distribution on the open interval -5 to 5, you must first scale rand by a factor of 10 (rand produces values on the open interval (0,1), and you need values on the range (-5,5)), and shift it up by 5, as seen below:

   shiftedCenteredSig = (10*rand(1,sig_length)) - 5 %scaled and shifted to be from -5 to 5

This pattern/recipe can be seen in the examples in the documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/rand.html:

> Examples Example 1 Generate values from the uniform distribution on
>   the interval [a, b]:
>
> r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);

The final code can be seen below:

```
sig_length = 200; % this task is part of a three plot figure so ignore the subplot part
subplot(2,2,1)
hold on
%sig = rand(1,sig_length); %note this is a uniform distribution on interval 0,1
sig = (10*rand(1,sig_length)) - 5 %scaled and shifted to be from -5 to 5
plot(1:sig_length,sig)
axis([1,sig_length,-5,5])
title('Signal')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your signal to go from -5 to 5,

```
sig = -5 + 10*rand(1,sig_length);
```

In general, for a random signal to go between `a` and `b`, use

```
a + (b-a)*rand(1,length);
```